# TableView Controller + Navigation Controller + Tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

What is the way to use multiple buttons on root view controller linked with different tab views in Xcode 4.5?

I have got 4 buttons on the home screen, I want the flow goes as when I tap on a button1 it should go to tab1 similarly when I tap on button2 tab2 should be open.

What should I do?
Please help. If any one know link to any tutorial or can provide me with guideline, it would be a major help 
Dummy Code Ignore this.

```
{
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the proper tag to buttons.

On the button click event, get the tag of the button. Select that controller using tag value.

```
tabController.selectedIndex = button.tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set up the IBActions for your buttons, in the method block you can navigate between between tab bar items items the `selectedIndex` property of the `tabBarController`.The index starts at 0 for the first tab bar item. If you have 4 tabs, the indices will be 0-3.

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```